# Can you take off a sweater while wearing headphones?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

This seems like a graph theory problem, but I'm not sure how to approach it.

To clarify potential ambiguities, let's set up the situation.

You are wearing a sweater (with one arm through each sleeve). You are also wearing a pair of earphones, which are connected to your stationary electronic device. Each ear is connected by one wire to the electronic device.

Can you take off your jacket without taking off your earphones?

Comment: Topologically, or practically?

Comment: It is possible, you should just try it!

Comment: I downvoted this question because I feel it's too vague, and it seems to me that depending on how you formalize it, it's just going to end up either trivially true, or trivially false.

Comment: Simply pull your arms out of the sleeves and then fit your entire body through the neck, pulling the sweater off over your legs. Easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

Not if you're holding the device in a hand and your headphones aren't snaked through your sleeve. Your hand, your arm, your head/neck, and the headphones forms a closed loop which prevents you from taking off the sweater.

Comment: You could change hands...

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, yes, if your electronic device is in your pocket.  While it seemingly forms a closed loop, it doesn't actually.

Thus, if you can pull your sweater from over your head and follow the wire into your pocket and fit the entire sweater into your picket to leave the electronic device stationary and exit the 'loop', then you're done.

Alternatively, taking the electronic device out of your pocket and letting it hang makes doing it 'reasonable'.

Comment: I'm going to downvote this since there are no link to a video of you actually trying this. :-)